# Adding LinearLayout programmatically in Android doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

The hierarchy is like this:

- RelativeLayout

  - LinearLayout (vertical)

    - FrameLayout (weight 5)

      - ImageView
    - View (weight 1)

The View is just a dummy view for spacing purpose.
I did it in the layout xml and it works.
But when I want to do it programmatically, the following codes do not work.

```
LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(this);
ImageView ladder = new ImageView(this);
FrameLayout ladderFL = new FrameLayout(this);
View dummyView = new View(this);
ladder.setImageResource(R.drawable.ladder1);
LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LayoutParams LLParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams ladderFLParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);
ladderFLParams.weight = 5f;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams dummyParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,0);
dummyParams.weight = 1f;

FrameLayout.LayoutParams ladderParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM);
ladder.setLayoutParams(ladderParams);
ladderFL.setLayoutParams(ladderFLParams);
dummyView.setLayoutParams(dummyParams);
LL.setWeightSum(6f);
LL.setLayoutParams(LLParams);

ladderFL.addView(ladder);
LL.addView(ladderFL);
LL.addView(dummyView);
((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.screenRL)).addView(LL);
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(this);
    LL.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LayoutParams LLParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    LL.setWeightSum(6f);
    LL.setLayoutParams(LLParams);


    ImageView ladder = new ImageView(this);
    ladder.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams ladderParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM);
    ladder.setLayoutParams(ladderParams);

    FrameLayout ladderFL = new FrameLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams ladderFLParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);
    ladderFLParams.weight = 5f;
    ladderFL.setLayoutParams(ladderFLParams);       
    ladderFL.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    View dummyView = new View(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams dummyParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0);
    dummyParams.weight = 1f;
    dummyView.setLayoutParams(dummyParams);
    dummyView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);



    ladderFL.addView(ladder);
    LL.addView(ladderFL);
    LL.addView(dummyView);
    RelativeLayout rl=((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.screenRL));
    rl.addView(LL);
```

I have just arranged your code for better understanding, also gave it a background color to get the clear picture as I dont know what you want, you can go through it. I Hope it is helpful. You should provide your working xml so we know exactly what you want.

Comment: I don't know why your codes work even I deleted those colors.
Maybe there is problem with my arrangement of codes.
Anyways, thanks!

Comment: @Piyush Gupta: What does screenRL represents?