# How can i achieve a certain layout

Tags: android, layout, view

What is the best way to have a layout like this for an android app?

[image: layout]

When the rownumber is even or 0, the row should have 2 columns.
Otherwise the row should have only 1 column

the rows have to be generated dynamically.
The cells should also have an image and some text in them.

What layout should i use: tablelayout or gridlayout? and which view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LinearLayout (vertical) as parent and LinearLayout (horizontal as children) and insde your children you can add one or two views based on your forloop count.

pseudo

```
rootLL = createLinearLayout(vertical)
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    childLL = createLinearLayout(horizontal)
    view1 = createView()
    view1.setWeight(1)
    childLL.addChild(view1)
    if (i%2==0)
    {
        view2 = createView()
        view2.setWeight(1)
        childLL.addChild(view2)
    }
    rootLL.addChild(childLL)
}
```

Comment: any idea how i can add a layout to another layout?

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065696/adding-linearlayout-programmatically-in-android-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

You just edit this code you can achieve this desired layout I designed this For you all the best You just take it as a Example and you may try Better than this

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```