# How to add multiple custom linearLayouts programmatically to listView item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I've got a quite irritating problem. My task is to add multiple LinearLayouts with custom XML template (And I don't know how many of Layouts there could be) with 2 TextViews inside (in each) into 1 ListView item.
Like this:[image]

Is it possible to do this in ArrayAdapter? Any help would be much appreciated!

Ok, i've managed to did something with help from Jonas Cz.
And this is what I've got.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parsed_csv_list_view_main_item, parent, false);
    }
    RealmResults<ParsedCSV> titles = parentFragment.getParsedCSVtitles();
    String[] parsedTitles = titles.get(0).getValues().split(";");
    String[] parsedValues = items.get(position).getValues().split(";");

    for (int i = 0; i < parsedValues.length; i++) {
        View holder = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parsed_csv_list_view_subitem, parent, false);
        TextView textViewTitles = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.parsed_csv_list_view_subitem_text_title);
        TextView textViewValues = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.parsed_csv_list_view_subitem_text_value);
        textViewTitles.setText(parsedTitles[i]);
        textViewValues.setText(parsedValues[i]);
        ((LinearLayout) convertView).addView(holder);
    }
    return ((View)convertView);
}
```

I had to cast my convertView to LinearLayout because just converView didn't had addView method. Ok, it's a shit but it works...with some problem.
Now, while scrolling, it seems like the amount of items in list increases for some reason. Can someone explain me why is this happening and how to fix it?

**FULLY WORKING SOLUTION FROM** JonasCz:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parsed_csv_list_view_main_item, parent, false);

    } else {
        ((LinearLayout) convertView).removeAllViews();
    }
    RealmResults<ParsedCSV> titles = parentFragment.getParsedCSVtitles();
    String[] parsedTitles = titles.get(0).getValues().split(";");
    String[] parsedValues = items.get(position).getValues().split(";");

    for (int i = 0; i < parsedValues.length; i++) {
       View holder = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parsed_csv_list_view_subitem, parent, false);
       TextView textViewTitles = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.parsed_csv_list_view_subitem_text_title);
       TextView textViewValues = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.parsed_csv_list_view_subitem_text_value);
       textViewTitles.setText(parsedTitles[i]);
       textViewValues.setText(parsedValues[i]);
       ((LinearLayout) convertView).addView(holder);
     }
    return ((View)convertView);
   }
```

Comment: You don't need multiple layouts, you can do this by defining format of listView item in one xml

Comment: @Apurva listView item format is defined. The problem is that there could be unknown amount of TextViews and I need to position them propperly

Comment: This mat not be the answer but you can get some hint. Here is how I have added textView programmatically, http://www.uploadbaz.com/m9bb9xokn97t

Comment: Are you using ArrayAdapter as-is or are you extending it ?

Comment: @JonasCz I'm using custom adapter which extends from ArrayAdapter

Comment: Try expandable listview can do something here

Comment: See my updated answer. The number of items increases because you are reusing your layout (convertView) and the views you add will stay there until you remove them.

Comment: @JonasCz  You are right. I've fixed this, thx a lot.

Comment: No problem :-)  Good question by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `getView()` method of your adapter, you inflate the main XML layout for the list item. Then you should loop through your data (Array, Cursor, whatever) and for each extra LinearLayout you want, create it, and add the TextViews, set their text, and add it to the main layout you inflated from XML. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19065951/4428462).

If you are re-using the view from the convertView parameter (which you should be doing), you must also ensure that your main layout is empty before using it, which you can do with`myMainListItemLayout.removeAllViews()`

A different way might be to put a listView inside your listview. (probably not such a good idea.)

Edit: Try changing your code as follows:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parsed_csv_list_view_main_item, parent, false);

    } else {
       ((LinearLayout) convertView).removeAllViews();
       }
    RealmResults<ParsedCSV> titles = parentFragment.getParsedCSVtitles();
    String[] parsedTitles = titles.get(0).getValues().split(";");
    String[] parsedValues = items.get(position).getValues().split(";");

    for (int i = 0; i < parsedValues.length; i++) {
        View holder = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parsed_csv_list_view_subitem, parent, false);
        TextView textViewTitles = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.parsed_csv_list_view_subitem_text_title);
        TextView textViewValues = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.parsed_csv_list_view_subitem_text_value);
        textViewTitles.setText(parsedTitles[i]);
        textViewValues.setText(parsedValues[i]);
        ((LinearLayout) convertView).addView(holder);
    }
    return ((View)convertView);
}
```

It's ugly, and probably slightly slow, but it works.

Comment: "If you are re-using the view from the convertView parameter (which you should be doing), you must also ensure that your main layout is empty before using it"  by this you mean (if convertView == null)?

Comment: Yes., if you have something like `convertView = LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item);` in that `if` statement