# Android place view in for loop

Tags: android, json, for-loop, android-listview, view

I have a problem. I am parsing a JSON file from a website, and want to go through it using a for loop and display the content each JSON object contains. Each JSON object should correspond to one for loop cycle, and it should contain a header where a title and some information get displayed, and a ListView with more information about the JSON object. How would I do that the best way ?

The amount of JSON object is unknown and changes, so I assume all the views have to be created programmatically using a for loop.

It should look somewhat like [this](http://dejoridavid.pe.hu/sasabus/travelling.php).

Comment: A ListView is what you need to display such repeating data, also a lot more efficient and faster than creating Views yourself.

Comment: Can a Listview contain other listviews? Also it should contain always one header and an unknown count of more lists following the header, so that would need another listview. How would I go about solving that?

Comment: Yes, you can put more sub-items inside a listview item. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429906/how-to-add-multiple-custom-linearlayouts-programmatically-to-listview-item/28431319#28431319), you have to dynamically add more TextViews to your list items as they are shown. The code to do it is quite ugly, but it's the best way and it works.

Comment: So the final product should look like the link I posted in the question. Is your link the way to do it?

Comment: Yes, it is. In fact the screenshot in my linked question is also very similar to what you want to achieve. Note that you should use one ListView item for each header, (ie. one ListView item for each bus route), and then add the TextViews for the times for each bus route. PS, sorry for typo in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to code that for you, but basically you could do the following:

1. Download JSON data with an `AsyncTask`
2. Parse JSON (you could GSON or Jackson) into a `List<>`
3. Use an `ArrayAdapter` or crate your own list adapter
4. Add the adapter to a `ListView`
5. Done

Comment: I already have all those steps, the thing I don`t understand is how would I make a listview inside another listview? It should always contain one header and an unknown count of following lists.