# ListView inside ListView item

Tags: java, android, performance

I want to ask one question, should I use ListView inside ListView item? Or I should redesign and remake my idea?

Example of ListView, but should be with couple sub items:

[image: Example of ListView, but should be with couple sub items]

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429906/how-to-add-multiple-custom-linearlayouts-programmatically-to-listview-item

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, but will it work fine with clickable items inside?

Comment: It should do. Let me know if it doesn't (maybe with a new question), and I'll try to help. Check [Android: ListView elements with multiple clickable buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1709166) for for a rough idea of how to wire up the click listener.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to combine both links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ListView` inside a `ListView` item is never a good idea. If you want sublists inside your list you can, for example, use a [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). However, with the migration from `ListViews` to `RecyclerViews` I would recommend you go and implement [this](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view) instead.

Comment: I wanted to use ExpandableListView, but I don't know can Iinsert items without subitems.

Answer (score 0):

A ListView will never work correctly embedded as an item in another ListView.  In fact, scrolling things inside other scrolling things is almost never what you really want to do, as it would be confusing to the user how to actually navigate your screen.

Comment: You thing I should carry out this subitems into another activity?

Comment: That makes sense to me.  You could use one list as a selector to drill into the next list of related items.

Comment: Thank you. I'll think about what you said.