# Add multiple custom LinearLayouts with Buttons to ListView item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, button, layout-inflater

I have a question related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429906/how-to-add-multiple-custom-linearlayouts-programmatically-to-listview-item).

Someone asked about adding multiple custom LinearLayouts programmatically to ListView item and this is almost what I need to do. In this question the author has TextViews in a LinearLayout. I have a Button (and some others) and when I click on this Button I want to inflate a new LinearLayout under this one with just clicked Button.

How to get current LinearLayout position so I could add new LinearLayout under it? Now I'm adding new LinearLayout at the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        //if you want get linearLayout at current position
        LinearLayout LINTOP = ((LinearLayout) parent.getChildAt(0));
        addLayout(LINTOP);
    }
});
```

add new layout like this under LINTOP

```
public void addLayout(LinearLayout parent){
    LinearLayout newLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    parent.addView(newLayout, 0, params);
}
```

Comment: .getChildAt is asking for qualifier to method and how to add new LinearLayout under this one?

Comment: are you using this LinearLayout LINTOP = ((LinearLayout) parent.getChildAt(0));

Comment: Under this or you want to add its child

Comment: I want new LinearLayout under this with just clicked button.

Comment: It is still adding at the bottom of LinearLayout

Comment: you can set index parent.addView(newLayout, 0, params);

Comment: How can I add first LinearLayout element? It is added after clicking Button outside ListView. I cannot use .setOnItemClickListener

Answer (score -1):

First of all, please use `RecyclerView` instead of ListView

You have a method called `getAdapterPosition()` which returns the position where the interaction happened. So in the ViewHolder if you so something like

`linearLayoutView.setOnClickListener 
    {
      Log.d("Position:"+getAdapterPostion());
    }`

That would give you the position. (The Above code is in Kotlin btw, so may look a bit different)