# Android generate Layout dynamically

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

I've to create a layout dynamically in android screen showing a list of items.
I know that I can use a ListView and a Custom Adapter to do this but items in the list must be shown in different ways according to their data and I'd like to know if I can generate layout by code.

I'm trying this way but I can see only the last item into my screen...seems like the other are suppressed by the last.

Here's my screen code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/allItemsLoadingPanel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indeterminate="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/allItemsContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="10dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.refractored.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/allItemsFab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        android:visibility="gone"
        fab:fab_size="normal"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/appColorPrimary"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/appColorPrimaryPressed"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/appColorPrimaryPressed" />
</FrameLayout>
```

and here's the layout of a single item that I Inflate and add to the LynearLayout called "allItemsContainer":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/allItemsIteTitle"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="16sp"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/allItemsIteUsername"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="14sp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/allItemsIteUsername"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
      android:paddingRight="10dp" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/allItemsIteText"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="12sp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/allItemsIteTitle"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
      android:paddingRight="10dp" />
  <RatingBar android:id="@+id/allItemsIteRatingbar"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:numStars="5"
      android:stepSize="0.1"
      android:layout_below="@+id/allItemsIteText"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:scaleX="0.5"
      android:scaleY="0.5"
      android:layout_marginRight="-50dp"/>
  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/allItemsComments"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

At the end of my loop into items I've added some items to the lynearLayout but I can see only one...
Can you help me?

Comment: post the code what you tried ...

Comment: What about using the search first?! There are thousands of solutions out there... Here is one of them http://stackoverflow.com/a/19065951/284308

Comment: I tried to search on web and I found some solutions that I tried to implement but the result is the same.
I've a linearlayout (orientation vertical) and I've to populate it inflating some different contents. At the end of the loop into my items list I can see that the parent LinearLayout has the children that I added (looking at the property LinearLayout.ChildCount) but I can see only the last on the screen

Comment: so how many "different ways" do you have? is it a number of 3 or 5? or really big number?

Comment: the list could contain many items also 50 or 100. My problem is that is a list of "posts" (like facebook for example) and some of them can have some comments to show and using a listview for do this could be more complicated. Looping my items and generating layout dynamically I think could be a good way but I didn't aspect this behaviur from my layout...

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about...

Comment: @Badozvora,can you please post your current code ?

Comment: I posted my code now

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can generate layout from code
You can have a LinearLayout defined in your layout. add your view to the linearlayout by using .addView(view)

Ex:

```
TextView textView  = new TextView(this)
linearLayout.addView(textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys I solved it: all my code was right but in my case I'd to add a ScrollView as  parent of my "allItemsContainer" LinearLayout. Now all is working fine.
Here's my screen code now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/allItemsLoadingPanel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indeterminate="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ScrollView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/allItemsContainer"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingTop="10dip" />
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.refractored.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/allItemsFab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        android:visibility="gone"
        fab:fab_size="normal"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/appColorPrimary"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/appColorPrimaryPressed"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/appColorPrimaryPressed" />
</FrameLayout>
```