# Android : Set gravity of a LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, gravity, layoutparams

I'm new in android programming.

I just discover that the xml is not the only way to set a layout. So, I'm trying to understand the programmatically set layout. I've been trying to change the position of the button. How can I set the layout gravity so that the button will be positioned in intended axes, let say  `bottom` and `center`?

Btw, is the `icicle` same thing as `savedInstanceState`?

Here's the coding that I stumbled upon. **Can you please show me the right way to set the gravity?**

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    LinearLayout one = new LinearLayout(this);
    myButton1 = new Button1(this);
    one.addView(myButton1,
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            0));
    myButton2 = new Button2(this);
    one.addView(mButton2,
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            0));
    setContentView(one);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, you are looking for

```
LinearLayout one = new LinearLayout(this);

        one.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER);  //to show LinearLayout gravity

        Button myButton1 = new Button(this);
        one.addView(myButton1,
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        0));
        myButton1.setText("First");
        myButton1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);   //to show text gravity in button

        Button myButton2 = new Button(this);
        one.addView(myButton2,
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        0));
        myButton2.setText("Second");
        myButton2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);   //to show text gravity
        setContentView(one);
```

> `icicle` is sometimes used as the name of the parameter.It's just a
>   placeholder for one of the formal parameters onCreate takes one Bundle parameter. It's up to you what to call it.

Some properties of LinearLayout https://stackoverflow.com/a/19065951/2826147

Comment: inform me if i can help you further@Mint

Comment: Thank you. It work. The button perfectly positioned at the bottom. savedInstanceState also one of the formal parameters then?

Comment: "icicle" is sometimes used as the name of the parameter because onSaveInstanceState() used to be called onFreeze().

Comment: Did you got solution to your que ?@Mint

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setGravity()`,

For example `button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);`

Comment: Thank you @HaykAvanesyan

Answer (score 1):

```
yourLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Simple as that

Comment: That's really simple. Thank you @Syn3sthete