# XML markup in the Android application

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

How do I distribute the objects so that the TextView is perfectly in the middle of the parent object, and the ImageButton is on the left. Tried to install for the parent element

```
android:gravity="center"
```

, as well as for the TextView itself

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

, but nothing comes out. I attach the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".add">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/backArrow"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/back_arrow" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/tenor_sans"
            android:text="@string/adder"
            android:textColor="#2C1E4D"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: [Try setting the gravity programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39485291/android-set-gravity-of-a-linearlayout-programmatically).

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you with your requirement

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".add">

 <LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="67dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/backArrow"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/back_arrow" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/aclonica"
        android:text="@string/adder"
        android:textColor="#2C1E4D"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

 </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```