# Creating layouts without an XML

Tags: android

I've read that layout XML files are interpreted to Java code, building a View hierarchy this way.

First, how and where is this done? Can someone link me to the place that does this interpretation?

Second, is it possible to create a complete layout without using XML files? If the answer is yes, is it useful in any way? (does it have advantages over XML files) Do big apps do this?

Comment: You can make graphics with java alone.

Comment: Yes, it is entirely possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've read that layout XML files are interpreted to Java code, building a View hierarchy this way.

Not by most definitions of the phrase "interpreted to Java code". The XML is parsed and used to create Java objects corresponding to the views expressed in the XML.

> Can someone link me to the place that does this interpretation?

[You are looking for `LayoutInflater`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html), presumably.

> is it possible to create a complete layout without using XML files?

Sure.

> is it useful in any way?

For trivial UIs (e.g., the whole content view is a `WebView`), it's a bit simpler and a tiny bit faster.

Note that many games will skip Java-based UIs entirely, rendering their output from C/C++ using OpenGL. Similarly, hybrid app frameworks (e.g., PhoneGap) will skip most of the Java-based UI work, as they render their UIs via Web technologies (HTML, CSS, JS, etc.).

Comment: You mean there are android apps that don't use Java at all? Are you referring to the Android NDK?

Comment: @Pilpel: "You mean there are android apps that don't use Java at all?" -- none that they write. There are some shims that the framework provides (e.g., `NativeActivity`). "Are you referring to the Android NDK?" -- for the C/C++ scenario, yes.

Answer (score 3):

A basic code will be like this, which I did on my blog:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // creating LinearLayout
        LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        // specifying vertical orientation
        linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        // creating LayoutParams  
        LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); 
        // set LinearLayout as a root element of the screen 
        setContentView(linLayout, linLayoutParam);

        LayoutParams lpView = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("TextView");
        tv.setLayoutParams(lpView);
        linLayout.addView(tv);

        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("Button");
        linLayout.addView(btn, lpView);


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams leftMarginParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        leftMarginParams.leftMargin = 50;

        Button btn1 = new Button(this);
        btn1.setText("Button1");
        linLayout.addView(btn1, leftMarginParams);


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams rightGravityParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rightGravityParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

        Button btn2 = new Button(this);
        btn2.setText("Button2");
        linLayout.addView(btn2, rightGravityParams);
    }
}
```

[image: Dummy]

Answer (score 1):

- **is it possible to create a complete layout without using XML files?**

Of course it is possible. But is it useful? It could be, if you want to add some elements programatically. For the entire UI, I think is not useful due to the potential of XML creation.

Example: [Adding LinearLayout programmatically in Android doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065696/adding-linearlayout-programmatically-in-android-doesnt-work)

```
LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(this);
LL.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LayoutParams LLParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

LL.setWeightSum(6f);
LL.setLayoutParams(LLParams);


ImageView ladder = new ImageView(this);
ladder.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

FrameLayout.LayoutParams ladderParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM);
ladder.setLayoutParams(ladderParams);

FrameLayout ladderFL = new FrameLayout(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams ladderFLParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);
ladderFLParams.weight = 5f;
ladderFL.setLayoutParams(ladderFLParams);       
ladderFL.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
View dummyView = new View(this);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams dummyParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0);
dummyParams.weight = 1f;
dummyView.setLayoutParams(dummyParams);
dummyView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);



ladderFL.addView(ladder);
LL.addView(ladderFL);
LL.addView(dummyView);
RelativeLayout rl=((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.screenRL));
rl.addView(LL);
```

- **Do big apps do this?**

General purpouse apps don't do it. But there are some specific cases that is useful to manage the UI programatically.

Answer (score 1):

**First question**:

The layouts you have in XML are a collection of Java objects, ex: `LinearLayout` resolves to a class in Java which has methods. When you are calling `findViewById` you're getting the reference to that object so you can call on the different methods for that view object. If you are curious about how a specific view works you can `CMD + Click` on the class name and get the decompiled source in Android Studio (the key will be different for Windows).

In terms of how the XML knows what to do, all of the `android:` related tags will be retrieved by that view's class known as an AttributeSet. From here methods are called to do the relevant things such as setting the text size or adding a child view to the class.

**Second question**:

Yes you can create a layout without XML. You can do something like extending from `LinearLayout` as a new class and then in the `onCreate` of your `Activity` you would pass in that view into `setContentView` instead of the layout reference.

Is this useful? In most cases not really, using XML for creating the view will be easier to read and easier to understand (yay graphical previews). If you need to create a custom view though, it can most certainly be done and there are plenty of reasons for doing it (such as extending functionality of `Button` or `LinearLayout`).

You can read more about views in [Google's official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

Answer (score 0):

Android XML files have been created to simplify layout creation. These files are interpreted from Java code and converted to objects. You can make your own classes (that inherit from View, ViewGroups..) and inflate XML layouts with custom attributes.

Sometimes it's better to generate views from Java code, for example when application need to render dynamic layout according to a data model. But it's not a good approach in my opinion create all the layout using Java (that yes, is always possible). The only adavantage i could see, is the avoided time to parse XML, but it's nothing respect layout code organization.

Answer (score 0):

XML files are inflated into a `View` object, yes.

"*How and where is this done*" -- depends where you are in the code.

In an Activity - you'll see `setContentView(View v)` or `setContentView(int layoutRes)`

In a Fragment - you'll see that `onCreateView` returns a `View` object. One that is typically gotten from a `LayoutInflater`

> is it possible to create a complete layout without using XML files?

Sure. In some cases, you don't need to write your own XML files - there are pre-defined ones from `android.R.layout.*`. For example, a ListView and an adapter.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(android.R.layout.list_content); // Pre-defined ListView
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list); // Existing List ID
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1); // Item Layout
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

But if you literally meant not using any XML files, then you can use something like this - bulid a `View` yourself, then `setContentView` at the end.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    ll.setLayoutParams(lp);

    EditText editText = new EditText(this);

    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("Click Me!");
    b.setOnClickListener(null);

    ll.addView(editText, 
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    ll.addView(b,
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    setContentView(ll);
}
```

> If the answer is yes, is it useful in any way? (does it have advantages over XML files) Do big apps do this?

I can't think of a reason it would be useful. Sure, you have more control over dynamic Views, but you can't visualize them as easily with the layout editor.

I'm sure there may be some instances where big apps do this, but are you planning on building a big app that requires large re-use of custom views?

Comment: I thought of a useful reason to create a layout in code instead of XML. If you publish a library with an XML layout, it has to be in AAR format, which requires the user to specify "@aar" in their dependency when using it and requires the user to specify "{transitive = true}" in their dependency if your library has dependencies. If you want to publish your library as a JAR file which doesn't have these requirements, you'll have to create your layout using code.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is possible to create android declarative UI using Jetpack compose removing the need of xml

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose

Answer (score 0):

You can create all the UI using this library that is based on android view system without xml files in a declarative way.

https://github.com/kaiserdavar/AndroidUI